# In how many ways can we form a committee of positive size from $7$ women, $4$ men so that there are at least $2$ women in the committe?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-set-theory, permutations

In how many ways can we form a committee of positive size from $7$ women, $4$ men so that there are at least $2$ women in the committee?

So the committee size must be $\geq 2$ and $\leq 11$ since it must contain at least 2 women.

for each size, we can have different combinations and it's really looking complex to me. 
Please help.

Comment: Are you asking for a formula for a committee of size $n$, or do you just want the total number of possible committees?  In either event, the easy way to do it is to compute the total number of committees, the subtract those with no women or exactly one woman.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are $2^{11}$ ways to form a committee.

There are $7 \cdot 2^4$ ways to form a committee with exactly one woman.

There are $2^4$ ways to form a committee with exactly zero women.

The answer is $2^{11} - 7 \cdot 2^4 - 2^4$.

Comment: I think total number of ways to form committee would be $2^{11} -1$  since we have to form a committee (and if nobody joins it then we don't get committee) what do you think

Comment: That's a good point. The actual answer remains unchanged though.

Comment: yes, no change in final answer.

Answer (score 4):

On a case by case basis, if the no. of women in the committee is $k\leq7$, then there are $\binom7k$ ways to select which of them are in the committee. Corresponding to that, there are $2^4$ ways to assign men to that committee.

You sum the expression for $k=2,\ldots,7$.

Comment: ${7\choose 2} \cdot 2^9$ is *not* the answer, as this yields duplicate combinations... In particular, your answer is larger than $2^{11}$, which is the number of possible committees altogether.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof: Thanks for pointing it out! Careless of me. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: Removed my downvote!

Comment: this is great approach too

Answer (score 0):

First assume 2 women are in the committee, now there are 5 women and 4 men left. We can now do casework for the rest. 1 person:2 | 2 people:3 | 3 people:4 | 4 people:5 | 5 people:5 | 6 people:4 | 7 people:3 | 8 people:2 | 9 people:1.
The answer is 29 combinations.

Note that each element is NOT distinct, only men and women are(if i'm reading this correctly).